# Promo buy 4 different and get 40% off (from 6 product selected)

Tags: promotions

My questionis simple, i am trying to set a promo for 6 shows. 
Buy 4 different shows and get 40% off. (easy part)
from a selection of 6 shows (part i cant get to work)

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This can often be an issue when trying to create a shopping cart rule based on individual products.  The reason is SKU needs to be enabled for Shopping Cart Price Rules. To do this in the admin go to:

> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

click SKU to edit it and change 'Use for Promo Rule Conditions' to 'Yes'.  What this does is allow Shopping Cart Price Rules to include SKU in the appropriate rule drop down options.

You can now buile the Shopping Cart Price Rule.  In the admin go to

> Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rules->Create New

Fill in the necessary items and then on the Conditions tab click the green '+' icon and choose 'Products Subselection'.  This will provide you with the following rule:

> If total quantity  is  ...  for a subselection of items in cart
>   matching ALL  of these conditions

Change the quantity to 4 (or you can change 'is' to another option like 'equal or greater than' if you want 5 and 6 shows to work also).  Then click the green '+' nested in this rule select 'SKU', change 'is' to 'is one of', and click '...' to open the text box (here you can enter SKUs separated by comma or you can click the Catalog icon to choose from your products. Click the green check mark to complete the product selection.)

Here is an example of how the output should look.

> If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
>
> If total quantity  is  4  for a subselection of items in cart matching
>   ALL  of these conditions:
>
> SKU  is one of  1,2,3,4,5,6

Save the rule and you should now be ready to start testing.